# Как найти слово в строке, и вывести его?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

есть например строка

```
param0_test1_param1_affiliatewire_%nameID%_test2_param2_param3
```

как мне в ней найти вхождение `affiliatewire_%nameID%` где `%nameID%` всегда разное слово
и вывести `%nameID%`
`affiliatewire_` <- встречается всегда!
примеры строк:

```
param0_test1_param1_affiliatewire_name1_test2_param2_param3
param0_test1_param1_affiliatewire_name_test2_param2_param3
param0_test1_param1_affiliatewire_trollolo_test2_param2_param3
```

Спасибо!!

Comment: https://regexper.com/#%2F%28affiliatewire_.%2B%3F%29_%2Fi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение:

```
<?php

$re = "/(?<=affiliatewire_)[^_\r\n]++/"; 
$str = "param0_test1_param1_affiliatewire_name1_test2_param2_param3
param0_test1_param1_affiliatewire_name_test2_param2_param3
param0_test1_param1_affiliatewire_trollolo_test2_param2_param3"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => name1
            [1] => name
            [2] => trollolo
        )

)
```

Пояснения по регулярному выражению:

`(?<=affiliatewire_)` - ищем текст, которому предшествует выражение `affiliatewire_`.
`[^_\r\n]++` - ищем максимально длинную последовательность из символов, кроме `_` и символов переноса строк.

---

Проверить работу PHP-кода можно на [Ideone](http://ideone.com/zh17o4), а регулярного выражения на [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uX3yT1/2).

Comment: а если вот так: ` /affiliatewire_(.[^_]*)_/`  ??

Comment: @JohnFreeman Не захватит значение, если оно будет последним в строке. Например, вот такое: `param0_test1_param1_affiliatewire_name` не найдет. Я дал вам ссылку на сервис для проверки.

Comment: огромное спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
/(?<=[_\n]|^)affiliatewire_([^_\n]*)/
```

Смысл регулярного выражения:

- текст `affiliatewire_` в начале строки, начале текста или после литерала `_`
- в первую группу захватываем весь последующий текст, кроме `_` и переноса строки

https://regex101.com/r/tC2iX5/1